# Gridview XmlDataSource from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net, gridview, google-docs-api, google-data-api, xmldatasource

I want to display data from google spreadsheet in a gridview. The spreadsheet is available publicly and therefore has a xml feed url :
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0An6MDOS8Tv_OdE9MSEtsRkVtZjQtakpkYnZ3WU8tcEE/1/public/values
All fields/items are inside the  element. The  items are wrapped with the  element.
I need the grid to display the following items:  and 
I've tried to set the Xpath of the xmldatasource to "feed/entry". The grid shows no items.
Any help get this grid working with that feed would be much appreciated.